# Pausing a perl script while SFTP transfers files

Tags: perl, sftp

FYI, I'm a complete newbie with Perl, as in I can spell it and only a little more so I'm trying to learn.  What I'm trying to accomplish is using SFTP to transfer files from a Windows machine to a Linux machine.

I've noticed that Perl issues the SFTP get command, but doesn't wait for the transfer to finish so when the Perl script tries to use a file it can't find it.  I know there is the sleep command, but the number and size of files will vary on a weekly basis so using sleep(600) seems a little silly.

Is there a standard way to pause a Perl script until SFTP finishes transferring all necessary files?

TIA.

Comment: How are you issuing the sftp command?

Comment: You should use a module, like `Net::SFTP`, rather than shelling out to the command-line utility.

Comment: @Wooble - What I was shown was to open an SFTP pipe then use `print SFTP "get remoteFileName \n";`

Comment: @Borodin - I'm going to guess that Net::SFTP is not available.  I tried using it based on an example and I get an error "Can't locate Net/SFTP.pm..."

Comment: It is not a core module, so needs installing. You may be lucky with `cpanm Net::SFTP`. Otherwise (or anyway) read [How to install CPAN modules](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using Net::SFTP might have solved this dilemma, but my workplace won't allow me to download and install stuff, especially in production.  So rather than waiting on the typical bureaucracy I did some more digging around and discovered this:

By calling SFTP in batch mode using a separate file that contains the SFTP commands, the Perl script has to wait for SFTP to finish executing the commands in the separate "command" file.  So by using the batch mode option, the Perl script is paused as long as it takes for SFTP to finish its work of file transfer.